# ¿Cómo hacer un Join en MySQL con un where para obtener todos los registros que coinciden con un ID?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un Status post, para hacer publicaciones.

Tengo dos tablas:

1. personas.
2. posts.

Lo que quiero es, cuando entro a la sesión de un usuario, me salgan sus respectivas publicaciones. Y lo único que me sale es una sola, y esa misma me sale en los demás usuarios. ¿Cómo hago una filtración según el usuario logueado y, claro, que me salgan todos sus posts?

Así es como estoy intentando obtener los registros:

```
<?php

$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN  
                      personas ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id") or die('Error: ' . 
                      mysqli_error($conn));


while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {
    $code = $posts_filas['Id'];
    $user_post_Id = $posts_filas['User_Id'];
    $title = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
    $contenido  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];
}


?>
<?php
echo $title;
echo $contenido;
?>
```

Tengo el **ID** del usuario logueado guardado en la variable **$my_id**.Esta la obtengo del archivo que me verifica la sesión.

Este es el archivo:

```
  <?php
   include('conexion.php');


     $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from personas where correo = 
    '$user_check' ");

  $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     $my_id = $fila['Id'];
     $login_session = $fila['correo'];
     $nombre = $fila['nombre'];
     $apellido = $fila['apellido'];
     $Avatar = $fila['Fotos'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
     header("location:start.php");
       }
   ?>
```

Comment: ¿Y en qué variable está el ID del usuario logueado?

Comment: @Mariano Ahi es donde quiero llegar.como pongo en la sentencia sql,algo como esto :"WHERE Id = 'my_id'".no tengo idea.

Comment: @Mariano que me una las dos tablas y despues me filtre segun el id del usuario

Comment: la consulta está bien y devuelve todos los posts. Deberías mover las 2 líneas de `echo` dentro del `while` para ver que imprime **todo**. En cuanto a filtrar sólo las del usuario logueado, depende de cuál sea el id del usuario, y deberías obtenerlo en el momento en que se loguea.

Comment: @Mariano Gracias resolvi lo de imprimirlo dentro del while.mi error.Pero la parte de obtener los post filtrados,no se como armar la consulta.Tengo el id del usuario en sesion,yo se hacerlo,pero acaso no debe ir todo junto dentro el query que he armado mas arriba?

Comment: deberías [edit] la pregunta mostrando en qué variable está el id de usuario. Cuando mencionás que lo tenés en sesión,, te referís a `$_SESSION[...]`??

Comment: @Mariano Algo asi

Comment: Debajo de tu pregunta encontrarás un enlace para **[edit]** la pregunta y aclararnos cómo está almacenado este valor.

Comment: @Mariano Listo.Lo he editado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podemos recorrer el array de resultados de la siguiente forma. Usaremos <strike>una tabla</strike> divs (a pedido del autor) para mostrar los datos más ordenados:

```
<?php

$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn,
                         "SELECT Id, Titulo, Contenido
                            FROM posts 
                           WHERE User_Id = $my_id")
                       or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));


while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //no hace falta obtener $user_post_Id, ya que es $my_id
    //$user_post_Id = $my_id 
    $title = $posts_filas['Titulo'];
    $contenido  = $posts_filas['Contenido'];

    echo '<div class="post_titulo">' . htmlentities($title) . '</div>'
        .'<div class="post_contenido">' . htmlentities($contenido) . '</div>';
}
```

Nótese que usamos la comparación con el id directamente en `WHERE User_Id = $my_id`. Además, por los datos que estás usando, no es necesario realizar el JOIN con la tabla `personas`.

Por otro lado, para imprimir los valores, usamos [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php).

Sin embargo, si quisieras utilizar datos de la tabla `personas`, se usaría el JOIN, tal cual como estabas intentando.

```
   SELECT posts.Id, 
          posts.Titulo, 
          posts.Contenido, 
          personas.Fotografia
     FROM posts
LEFT JOIN personas
       ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id 
    WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id
```

Por último, el código que estás usando para obtener el id del usuario logueado, presenta un serio problema de seguridad. Deberías leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127) y usar una sentencia preparada en tu primer consulta.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.Una ultima duda.Como imprimo esos resultados en DIVs diferentes.y no en una  tabla.?

Comment: @luis Editado para mostrar en divs... Por cierto, no dejes de leer la pregunta enlazada en el último párrafo (es importante asegurar que un usuario malicioso no pueda borrarte toda la tabla).

Comment: Mis disculpas, no me habia fijado @Mariano

Comment: @Mariano Disculpa.Todo eso me funciona,pero hay algo mas que quiero.Me explico.Esa consulta solo me atrae datos de una tabla.pero y si quiero datos también de la otra tabla,tales como la foto del usuario????

Comment: @luis editado usando un JOIN

Comment: @Mariano En realidad eso era lo que queria al principio.tomar datos de las 2 tablas segun el id del usuario que esta guardado en la variable "$my_id".

Comment: @luis no era necesario el JOIN en tu pregunta inicial, y cuanto más simple la sentencia, más eficiente

Comment: @Mariano pero eso fue en la inicial.Pero creo que ahora si es necesario.Verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba:

```
$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN  
                  personas ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id AND  posts.User_Id=".$my_id) or die('Error: ' . 
                  mysqli_error($conn));
```